# Source of COVID-19 Death toll by age group?

Tags: covid-19-datasets

Does anyone knows of a dataset containing death toll data by age group? So far I had to stitch data from diverse sources and different timeframes. I've been able to infer directional IFRs from my analysis but I'd like to increase sample size. You can view my analysis here https://www.outhiink.com/covid-19-special-report/

Comment: Welcome to Medical Sciences! Please take the [tour] and read the [help]. For [reasons mentioned in this post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411) and in [ask], we require some degree of prior research when asking questions. *See [this list of helpful resources](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/a/784)*. Please help us to help you and [edit] your question to provide more information on what you have read on this subject, what made you ask this question, and any problems you are having understanding your research. If you found nothing, what did you Google?

Comment: I just googled `covid-19 mortality rate by age` and found the data you're looking for in the first three hits. Scanning down the results I see it's available on many more sites.  You might want to start [here](https://www.cdc.gov/nchs/nvss/vsrr/covid_weekly/index.htm).

Comment: And if you want a more precise answer, you have to clarify what you mean by "death toll" (Excess mortality by age? CFR by age?)

Comment: Thanks Carey but I already had this link. I'm looking for actual number of deaths by age group.eg how many died between 50-60, 60-70 etc.  Not case related, not CFR related, just actual number of deaths per age group. Trust me it's not easy to find for most countries. I have US though until they stopped publishing it.

Comment: Okay, then you need to clarify your question by being more specific about what you're looking for, as @Fizz commented.

Comment: Have you looked at [EuroMOMO](https://www.euromomo.eu/graphs-and-maps)?

Comment: Folks death toll means number of deaths. Mortality rate is a totally different concept.

Comment: I'll ask again. Does anyone knows of a maintained dataset with death data by age group? Thanks

Comment: Fizz, Euromomo does not segregate data by disease.

Answer (score 1):

[This Opendata.SE question](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/16251/covid-19-clinical-data-or-statistics) has a number of answers that have links to raw data that you can perform your own analyses by age and other demographics. There is one answer that by the description gives a full set of data for [South Korea](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/17366/10235).

[Here](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/17321/10235) is a link to a data set with the largest volume collected from across the world, I would expect that there will be biases in collecting the data due to the nature of the collection, but you may be able to glean something useful from it.